# Opencart how to put sort by to this site using vqmod

Tags: sorting, opencart, vqmod

How to put sort by to this site using vqmod?
(link: http://togo-online.com/index.php?route=seller/catalog-seller/profile&seller_id=1)

How can I connect `vqmod sort` via `xml` to the link?

Please help me!

Comment: @Codeisir can you help me about this?

Comment: Your site is under maintenance mode. Can you please enable to proper mode then after i will let you know your answer.

Comment: Its ok now i disable the maintenance mode..Kindly Check please..

Comment: i add sorting using category but i know this is not the correct sorting

Comment: all i need is that i can sort using category in this page link: http://togo-online.com/index.php?route=seller/catalog-seller/profile&seller_id=1

Answer (score 0):

Your sorting URL is transferring to category page, This is wrong URL. You need to change URL of sorting like,

> http://togo-online.com/index.php?route=seller/catalog-seller/profile&seller_id=1&category_id=?&order=ASC

Comment: Yes can you help about its coding of sorting this

Comment: You can check this http://togo-online.com/index.php?route=seller/catalog-seller/products&sort=pd.name&order=ASC&seller_id=1  but all i need is to sort category not alphanumeric of the product